# Python: create an array within an object

Tags: python, arrays, oop

I am new to OOP, so please forgive me for asking a beginner's question.

I create a class "mittelKlasse" which has a few internal variables, an array among them.

```
class mittelKlasse:

    _depth = 1
    _array = []
    _index = 0
    
    def __init__(self, depth):
        self._depth = depth
        for i in range (self._depth):
            self._array.append (0)
        self._index = 0
        
        if args.debug > 2:
            print (self._depth, len(self._array))
```

When an object is instantiated, an array is created, its size is given in the parameter "depth".

I tested my class:

```
mittel_1 = mittelKlasse (5)
mittel_2  = mittelKlasse (20)
```

I expect the debug output `5 5` and `20 20`.
Instead, I get `5 5` and `20 25`.

It means that the objects `mittel_1` and `mittel_2` have their own `_depth`, but share the same `_array`. When instantiating the second object, no new array is created (what I want to happen), but the existing array is appended.

I want both objects to have their own arrays. How can I do it?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### In Python, you can access both *instance attributes* and *class attributes* using `self`.

Python will first search for the attribute in the instance and if it won't find it, it will move to searching it in the class.

In your example, you are creating 3 class attributes: `_depth`, `array` and `_index`.

Then in your `__init__` you defined instance attributes `_depth` and `_index` shadowing the class attributes, and you changed the class attribute `_array`.

If you printed the attributes of `mittel_1` and then the attributes of `mittlelKlasse` using `.__dict__` or `vars()` like so:

```
print(mittel_1.__dict__)
print(mittelKlasse.__dict__)
```

You would have seen that the `mittel_1` object only has 2 attributes to it:

```
{'_depth': 5, '_index': 0}
```

and that the class `mittelKlasse` has:

```
...'_depth': 1, '_array': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '_index': 0,...
```

(printed it after the creation of mittel_2)

---

If you want each object to have its own (instance attribute) `_depth`, `_array` and `_index` then you have to define them for each instance in the `__init__` method.

##### Fixed version:

```
class mittelKlasse:
    # Remove the definition as class attributes
    # _depth = 1 
    # _array = []
    # _index = 0
    
    def __init__(self, depth):
        # Define instance attributes here
        self._depth = depth
        self._array = []
        self._index = 0
        for i in range (self._depth):
            self._array.append (0)
        

        print (self._depth, len(self._array))
            
mittel_1 = mittelKlasse (5)
mittel_2  = mittelKlasse (20)
```

##### Output:

```
5 5
20 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not declare the variable at the class level, because they are going to be *class* variables instead of instance variables e.g.:

```
class mittelKlasse:
    _depth = 1    # <- no here
    _array = []   # <- no here
    _index = 0    # <- no here
```

Inside the `__init__`, assigning the variables to `self` will work.

Answer (score 2):

The various variables should be related by `self` to the instance of the Class. For example:

```
class mittelKlasse:
    def __init__(self, depth):
        self._depth = depth
        self._array = []
        for i in range (self._depth):
            self._array.append (0)
        self._index = 0
    
        print (self._depth, len(self._array))
    
mittel_1 = mittelKlasse (5)
mittel_2  = mittelKlasse (20)
```

gives:

```
5 5
20 20
```